# Why is my queue hanging with asyncio event loop

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I'm launching a new process (*edit the same thing applies to a new thread*) for computations from an async event loop. The new process has it's own asyncio event loop running and runs fine without any kind of blocking behavior.

I created two queues (`multiprocessing.Queue` or `multiprocessing.Manager.Queue`), one for outgoing messages, and another for incoming messages. I get the same behavior with both queues. The queue for outgoing messages is working fine, as I put/get a message on the queue with :

```py
await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, self.incoming_queue.put, msg)
msg = await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, self.incoming_queue.get, True, 1)
```

However, when I attempt to run the same `get()` command in my original asyncio application using the asyncio `run_in_executor` command, it just hangs. The event loop itself seems fine and responsive.

Disabling the working queue doesn't change things, and neither does the executor (default, thread, or process).

Ideas?

Comment: Can you create a minimal example that we can run to observe the same behavior?

Comment: As I continue debugging, I've learned that it may have to do with some configuration of the event loop in Django Channels (the application I'm trying to integrate in to). I created a simpler asyncio loop to run the code in, and each queue seems to run fine. I'll update in a few hours if anything changes, and I may delete the question at that time if I don't have any more helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to make an answer here based on my investigation. In short: what works in a new event loop in a new process does NOT work in the Django Channels event loop for one reason or another.

My current solution is to manually create a new thread to run my synchronous listener in. I'm looking into options for why the Channels event loop wouldn't work in my use case.